# hash intersection possible with redis+lua?

Tags: lua, redis, lua-table

I have a use-case where I need to compute similarities between a lot of sets to create a simple recommendation engine. I was looking at the Jaccard coefficient and other similarity coefficient formulae but one thing was common between them: the items inside the sets cannot be repeated (correct me if I'm wrong here).

I wrote my own function in PHP to do a custom hash intersection with the logic being that:

1. **`arr1`**: an array whos keys are ids of items and the values are their corresponding quantities.
   This represents a user's wishlist.
2. **`arr2`**: is the same as **`arr1`** however it represents another user's inventory.
3. The logic I need for this custom intersection is that the owner of the wishlist does not care if the seller has 100 of item1. If he only wants 4 of it, only 4 is counted.

I need a very fast way to intersect the sets but the usual similarity coefficient formulae involve intersecting and union of sets, which can be not as fast as I want when comparing one set with say, 200k others. Here is where I am at so far:

```
function my_similarity_coefficient ($arr1, $arr2) {

    $matches = 0;
    $total = 0;

    if (count($arr2) == 0)
        return 0;

    foreach ($arr1 as $id => $qty) {

        $total += $qty;

        if (!array_key_exists($id, $arr2))
            continue;

        $matches += min($qty, $arr2[$id]); // do not match more than what user wants

    }

    return $matches / $total;

}
```

I tried intersecting two redish hashes in PHP. The sizes are `arr1[67]` and `arr2[231]` respectively. The coefficient was calculated in under an outstanding 61.98µsec (up to 266.075µsec at worst). This number balloons up to 905.037µsec-3337.86µsec if I try to get the data from Redis to PHP.

I want to keep the bottleneck away from transporting the data from redis to PHP so I was wondering if it is possible to program this custom intersection in lua (or maybe even c++), and if it's possible, won't it suffer from the same bottleneck since it's also fetching it from pointA to pointB or will it not suffer the fetch bottleneck because the data is already local to it?

I'm not familiar with lua but I'm not looking to be spoonfed with exact code. Since there is little resource for lua on the internet relating to what I actually want to achieve, I wanted to pick a few brains here first while I am searching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see. First, here is your PHP code directly translated to Lua. I have kept the same variable names here but what you call "Array" in PHP is called "Table" in Lua.

```
local my_similarity_coefficient = function(arr1, arr2)

  local matches = 0
  local total = 0

  if next(arr2) == nil then
    return 0
  end

  for id, qty in pairs(arr1) do

    total = total + qty

    if arr2[id] then
      matches = matches + math.min(qty, arr2[id])
    end

  end

  return matches / total

end
```

Note that this code can divide by zero if `arr1` is empty, but yours does as well.

Let's try it:

```
local arr1 = {
  a = 3,
  b = 5,
  c = 8,
}

local arr2 = {
  a = 2,
  c = 10,
  d = 7,
  e = 21,
}

print(my_similarity_coefficient(arr1, arr2)) -- 0.625
```

Now let's use Redis. First, let's create the test data.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hmset arr1 a 3 b 5 c 8
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> hmset arr2 a 2 c 10 d 7 e 21
OK
```

This script does what your want, not in the most efficient way (there could be fewer calls to `redis.call`) but in a simple way, so you can understand it and optimize it if needed:

```
local k1, k2 = KEYS[1], KEYS[2]
local matches, total = 0, 0

if not redis.call("exists", k2) then return 0 end

local qty, qty2
for _, id in ipairs(redis.call("hkeys", k1)) do
  qty = tonumber(redis.call("hget", k1, id))
  total = total + qty
  qty2 = tonumber(redis.call("hget", k2, id) or 0)
  matches = matches + math.min(qty, qty2)
end

return tostring(matches / total)
```

Let's call it:

```
$ redis-cli eval "$(cat the_script.lua)" 2 arr1 arr2
"0.625"
```

Success!

The important point to note is the types conversion: the values (quantities) are converted to integers with `tonumber` (Redis returns strings), and we convert the result to a string because if we returned a floating point number Redis would truncate it to an integer (here 0).

**EDIT -** OK, talking about optimization and not saying how is not nice, so here is an easy one:

```
local k1, k2 = KEYS[1], KEYS[2]
local matches, total = 0, 0

if not redis.call("exists", k2) then return 0 end

local t1 = redis.call("hgetall", k1)

local id, qty, qty2
for i=1,#t1,2 do
  id, qty = t1[i], tonumber(t1[i+1])
  total = total + qty
  qty2 = tonumber(redis.call("hget", k2, id) or 0)
  matches = matches + math.min(qty, qty2)
end

return tostring(matches / total)
```

Comment: looks good. it seems you have already done the work for me. is it possible to do a hgetall into a table though to make it in one trip?

Comment: You mean hgetall k2? This will be a good idea only when there are lots of intersections between the two docs. Moreover hgetall returns `{key1, val1, key2, val2}` and not `{key1 = val1, key2 = val2}` so you have to convert. The current code does a single network trip but `O(n)` Lua - C trips inside Redis, so it may be faster, or not. So to sum up: it's possible, but you should benchmark it.

Comment: Okay thanks alot! If I could upvote twice I would! :)

Comment: Well that turned out really strange. I did a 1:40k run:
The first one taking all the arr2 out one by one from redis and doing the coefficient calculation in native PHP.
The other one is calling $redis->eval() per iteration.
Native PHP = 16s
PHP lua eval = 21s
And it was consistent scores at that. Do you think I might have done something wrong? Or this is to be expected?

Comment: Okay, I think I finally nailed it. This runs in only 3 seconds: http://pastebin.com/B1ALJanR which I think is pretty good. Not unless you can see somewhere I can optimize it on. :)

Comment: Nice :) I don't see anything obvious to optimize.